# How did these two sentences "I am looking for a responsible man" and "I am looking for the man responsible" come to take on different meanings?

Tags: etymology, phrases, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, linguistics

The first sentence "I am looking for a responsible man" means that I am looking for someone who can be trusted whereas the second sentence "I am looking for the man responsible" means that I am looking for the man who has done something.

In the former, responsible acts as a prepositive adjective while in the latter a postpositive adjective.

What are the perhaps etymological or linguistic reasons that led to these two sentences with the main word 'responsible' take on different meanings?

Comment: I think **the man responsible** here is shortened from  **the man who is responsible for blah blah**

Comment: I think in this case, it's an informal speech, so the verb got omitted between 'man' and 'responsible,' and also the tail that expounds on the adjective. If we include the verb and the tail, then it becomes "I'm looking for the man who is responsible...(for something)" If we don't add the last tail 'for something' both attributive and postpositive sentences mean the same.